# Javascript fetch API in react-flux

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I am studying the [flux-react-router-example](https://github.com/gaearon/flux-react-router-example) by @Dan Abramov, I notice in the Fetch API code [here](https://github.com/gaearon/flux-react-router-example/blob/master/scripts/utils/APIUtils.js#L41-L57): The fetch API has a return promise that has a nested return inside:

```
return fetch(url).then(response =>
response.json().then(json => {
  const camelizedJson = camelizeKeys(json);
  const nextPageUrl = getNextPageUrl(response) || undefined;

  return {
    ...normalize(camelizedJson, schema),
    nextPageUrl
  };
})
```

);

I am confused with this nested returns, why is this used here? Why not just return response.json()?

Seems like if I do the same thing, I will get a undefined value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The json retrieved from the response is

1. converted to camelCase using [humps](https://github.com/domchristie/humps)
2. un-nested using [normalizr](https://github.com/gaearon/normalizr) for easier handling in combination with the redux store
3. enriched with the next page url, parsed from the `link` header

More discussion and reasoning about why storing nested response objects in the store is usually a bad idea can be found at the [React JS Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reactjs/jbh50-GJxpg).

Comment: thanks for your answer, I am actually curious how a return statement in a response.json() works. From what I understand, this will create a undefined value when used outside

Comment: The request is made using githubs [fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch) polyfill, which is based on the [polyfillable parts](http://github.github.io/fetch/) of the whatwg fetch spec. the body methods like `text()` and `json()` return promises yielding the results that can then be chained upon using a standard promise chain - which is what happens in this example.

long story short: the return value of the `json()` call is a promise.